# Android, Handle touch and send it to bottom view

Tags: android, android-activity, touch

I'm creating a `HelpActivity` above my `MainActivity`, `HelpActivity` is almost transparent.I want show to user the place he should touch to do staff, but I don't want `finish()` my `HelpActivity` and then let the user to touch that place, I need when user touches the place in `HelpActivity` the exact place on `MainActivity` simulate like when user touches it.

I hope you understand me.

Comment: I want to focus on one thing here is: when you are showing help activity above main activity, that your main activity is in the background in the stack. Only Help activity is in foreground. Maybe passing the main activity object to help activity can solve your problem by calling object function of main activity on it. I don't know this will work or not but at least you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your over complicating the situation.

If you want to be able to allow touch to pass to a view lower in the Z-axis keep all the views in the same hierarchy (i.e. Activity) - then you will get this behaviour for free rather than using a massive hack to achieve something the OS will do automatically.

**OR use something like [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview)**